ECS CapacityProviderReservation Triggers Unnecessary EC2 Instance Launch in ASG Despite Low Task Load
I'm currently experiencing an issue where my Auto Scaling Group (ASG) is launching a second EC2 instance automatically, even though only one task is running, and CPU consumption is low. I need help understanding why this happens and how I can address it.
Infrastructure Overview:

EC2 Instances: T3.Large instances.
Auto Scaling Group (ASG):

Minimum: 0
Maximum: 3
Desired capacity varies depending on scaling policies.


ASG Scaling Policies:

Step scaling policy for high and low CPU utilization with alarms set at thresholds.
Target tracking policy based on the CapacityProviderReservation metric with an 80% threshold.



ECS Task and Service Configuration:

ECS Task Definition:

CPU capacity allocated per task: 1024 CPU units (equivalent to 1 vCPU).
The task is configured to scale based on service CPU utilization, with policies set to add more tasks if usage surpasses 80% and scale down if it drops below 20%.


ECS Service:

Runs a single task initially and scales based on traffic and CPU utilization.
The CapacityProviderReservation scaling policy is configured to trigger a scale-up if the reservation surpasses 80%.



Observations:

The ASG launches a second EC2 instance even when the existing instance has only one running task with no significant CPU usage. When I tested my container on an EC2 instance without any scaling, it only consumed 4 CPU units at idle.
The ECS service shows CPU utilization spikes reaching 102%, which surpasses the set scale-up threshold (80%). However, this does not align with the actual container workload, which should be low given there is no traffic.

Key Policies:

ASG Step Scaling Policies:

High CPU utilization policy triggers when CPU utilization exceeds 1600 units for a period.
Low CPU utilization policy removes instances when CPU falls below 400 units.


Target Tracking Policy:

Monitors the CapacityProviderReservation metric at an 80% threshold to maintain cluster capacity.



Question:
Why is the CapacityProviderReservation policy consistently triggering the launch of a second EC2 instance even though:

The task has sufficient CPU capacity (1024 units).
The actual task CPU usage should be minimal at startup (around 4 units observed).
Only one task is running, and it doesn't seem to require scaling up the cluster?

I'm looking for guidance on how to interpret the CapacityProviderReservation metric behavior correctly and what changes I might need to make to avoid unnecessary scaling actions. Any insights on aligning the scaling behavior with my actual task load would be greatly appreciated.

What I tried:

Increasing Task CPU Capacity: I configured the task to have a higher CPU capacity (1024 units, equivalent to 1 vCPU) to ensure it would not reach the CPU utilization threshold (80%) too quickly. My aim was to provide the task with ample CPU headroom to handle initial loads without scaling up unnecessarily.

Monitoring Task Behavior: I observed the task running on a single EC2 instance without load, noting that it only used around 4 CPU units at idle, which is far below the scale-up threshold.


What I Was Expecting:
Initially, I expected that only one task would run on a single EC2 instance without triggering additional instance launches unless traffic or CPU utilization significantly increased.
